# Classes vs Objects? as3

Tags: actionscript-3, class, object

I creat two people that are instances of the Person Class

```
 var  personOne = new Person;
 var  personTwo = new Person;
```

later I create an Object called Chuck;

```
 var Chuck = {age:32, name:"Chuck"}
```

Now I want to make personOne be a "person" with the properties of "chuck:Object";

```
Cannot convert Object to Display Object. // Output
```

Comment: I figured it out. var Chuck = new Person;

Comment: Then ---   
Chuck.age = 32; etc...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set properties of an object when it is created, you can let the constructor accept them as parameters.

For example:

```
package
{
    public class Person
    {
        private var _age:uint, _name:String;

        public function Person (age:uint, name:String)
        {
            _age = age;
            _name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

You use it like so:

```
 var chuck:Person = new Person(32, "Chuck");
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not what you need, but it is what you asked.

```
var personOne :Person = new Person();
var object:Object = { age:23, name:"efefw" };
for (var prop:String in object)
{
    personOne[prop] = object[prop];
}
```

This will only work for public properties.